# What does it mean when we use a variable like a Template in C++?

Tags: c++

I am reading a C++ book. I encountered a code similar to the following:

```
int foo=3;
if(foo<1>(3))
    cout<<"hello world!"<<endl;
```

So, how is the `int foo` being used as a template? What does it mean?

**I BELIEVE :** This is a huge ambiguity of C++ because If we have a template code like this, what will happen?? How does C++ handle this **ambiguity**?

```
template <int N>
  void foo( const int t )
  {
     // ....
  }
```

Comment: "How an int var is used as a template"? It is not.

Comment: Ok. then what does it mean?

Comment: Variables and type names are independent. The language grammar allows it to determine whether `foo` is a variable or type/template depending on the context.

Comment: What does `1 + 2` mean? What does `4 < 3` mean? Those are all things you can derive from the language grammar...

Comment: I didn't understand why did I get the the negative vote!! What is wrong with this question? I have seen exactly this code without any definition and I asked my question!

Comment: @AmirJalilifard As MooingDuck comments below his answer, does the book explain later that there are no templates involved in the example? Or did you stop reading and rush over to post a question as soon as you saw the example?

Comment: No. I didn't see any definition. Of course reading the book's definition is much easier than asking question here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is absolutely bizarre code, so if the book doesn't explain it, burn the book and demand a refund.  The summary is: it's not a template.  It's a less than comparison, and a greater than comparison.

```
if(foo<1>(3))
```

Is identical to

```
if( (foo<1) >3)
```

Which is nearly identical to

```
bool first = (foo < 1);  //false since `foo` is 3
bool second = (first > 3); //false evaluates to zero, so this is false as well
if (second) //this is never entered
    cout<<"hello world!"<<endl; //compiler probably doesn't even generate this.
```

---

As for your question about template ambiguities, the language clearly specifies somewhere what the default is, though it often isn't the one you want.  I compiled your sample and found that it emits this: `warning: comparisons like 'X<=Y<=Z' do not have their mathematical meaning [-Wparentheses]` http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49479996464507dc.  So we know it's still being interpreted as operators and ignoring the templates for this case.

But yes, there are many places where C++ is "ambiguous" in these ways.  The most common is the "most vexing parse".

```
struct A {};
struct B {
    B(A a) {}
};
int main() {
    B obj(A());
```

You'd expect this to create an `B` named `obj` using a default-constructed `A`, but instead it declares a function named `obj` that returns a `B` and it's parameter is *itself* a function that takes nothing and returns an `A`.  Then when you attempt to use it as a variable, you get all sorts of strange and confusing errors: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6fd627be8529b26

A much more insidious version is this:

```
template <class T>
struct A {
    static int v;
};
template<>
struct A<int>
    using v = float;
};
template<class T>
struct B {
    B() {
        A<T>::v;
    }
};
```

Inside `B`, it's hard if not impossible to tell if `v` is a type or a variable.  This one was so bad that C++ had to add a special keyword `typename` so that programmers could tell the compiler that it was actually a type, because the compiler would always assume it was a variable.

Comment: It doesn't even matter what the value of `foo` is, `second` will always be `false`. Can't believe a book contains an example like this!

Comment: I'm with you.  Burn the book.

Comment: @Praetorian: I'd expect the book says something akin to "this looks like a template but is really two comparison operators"

Comment: Nice! I would have stared at that code for a long time before figuring out what it was doing. I haven't read that book, but I would guess it's in a section talking about how whitespace doesn't matter in C++.

Comment: @ Cássio Renan It was a mistake putting the Book's name here! But Yes! I am from Brasil too!! It is very famous and full of errors too!

Comment: @CássioRenan: Correction: "The Deitels _are_".  Paul J. Deitel and Dr. Harvey M. Deitel

Comment: As I said this is a huge ambiguity of C++ because If we have a template code like this, what will happen?? How does C++ handle this ambiguity?

Comment: @MooingDuck haha, didn't know that. Amir: It's not an ambiguity: `int foo` would hide the template `foo` if declared in a narrower scope, and cause a compiler error if declared in the same scope.